# Input field being cut off by keyboard

Tags: flutter, soft-keyboard

The keyboard is cutting off part of the input field

I am using a TextFormField

[image: keyboard cutting off part of input field]

is there anyway to push the screen up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `false` should do it

```
Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
body:..
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add scroll padding in TextFormField

```
scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
```